# create time duration using excel vb

Tags: excel, vba

i'm have some driver data log data that consist of time in and time out (24 hour format)eg:

```
Name        Time in     Time Out

Frank        5:30       7:55

             11:35      16:35

             17:24      19:20
```

regarding this data i have some trouble to process into something like this

[result](https://i.imgsafe.org/0091be59f2.jpg)

because i have hundreds of data like this, how to process data like that into the result using excel vb? thank you

Comment: you can use VBA which is in excel. It gives you option to create macros. And in your current situation you will need something, that will parse time data, into cells. From your image, you just need information about hours and from start end end time you will set background color and border to current cells.

Comment: You can use loop through your data and  "Hour" function to get cell locations, and color the range.

Comment: Just on a side note: I like the way you are handling / showing the data: coming in at 5:30 shows in your graph as "came in at 5:00" and the absence between 16:35 and 17:24 of almost one hour doesn't even show at all. So, once people know the weak point of your graph it might seem as if someone was "in" all day long while he/she actually only stayed there for two and a half hours: in 5:30 out 6:10 in 7:30 out 8:10 in 9:30 out 10:10 ...

Comment: @wingz - Would I be correct in assuming that at this point you have abandoned this question and will not be contributing or even showing any original effort (working or not) that you have come up with toward a solution?

Comment: i have not abandoned this question since this is my primary project, and still working out the solution for this matter...

Comment: @wingz - It would be prudent to show what you have come up with so far. Add any error messages you've received (noting the line that produces them) and indicate where you are having trouble continuing. [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) is a site where you get help with your work; it is not a site where you get your work done for you.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, your proposed hour-by-hour division does not seem to lend accuracy or credence to the graph's results. I would suggest a maximum of 10 minute segments with the start and stop times rounded off to those divisions.

Midnight to 01:00 am is considered hour zero and 11:00 pm to midnight is considered the twenty-third hour. While the times could be converted, that doesn't seem to be productive coding. Educate your users to use the proper time brackets instead.

```
Option Explicit

Sub create_time_duration()
    Dim h As Long, trw As Long, drw As Variant
    With Worksheets("Sheet6")
        .Range("E:EU").EntireColumn.Delete
        For h = 0 To 23
            With .Cells(1, 6 + h * 6).Resize(1, 6)
                .EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = 0.6
                .Merge
                With .Resize(1, 1)
                    .NumberFormat = "hh:mm"
                    .Value = TimeSerial(h, 0, 0)
                    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                    .Font.Size = 10
                End With
            End With
        Next h

        For trw = 2 To .Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
            If Not IsEmpty(.Cells(trw, "A")) Then
                drw = Application.Match(.Cells(trw, "A").Value2, .Columns("E"), 0)
                If IsError(drw) Then
                    .Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = .Cells(trw, "A").Value2
                    drw = Application.Match(.Cells(trw, "A").Value2, .Columns("E"), 0)
                End If
                .Cells(drw, "F").Resize(1, 144).NumberFormat = ";;;"
            End If
            .Cells(drw, (Hour(.Cells(trw, "B").Value) + 1) * 6 + _
                        CLng(Minute(.Cells(trw, "B").Value) / 10)). _
                        Resize(1, Hour(.Cells(trw, "C").Value - .Cells(trw, "B").Value) * 6 + _
                                  CLng(Minute(.Cells(trw, "C").Value - .Cells(trw, "B").Value) / 10)) = 1
        Next trw

        With .Range(.Cells(2, "E"), .Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp))
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count, 144).Offset(0, 1)
                .FormatConditions.Delete
                .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(F2)"
                With .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count)
                    With .Interior
                        .Color = vbGreen
                    End With
                    .StopIfTrue = False
                End With
            End With
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

I will leave it to you to create any cell borders that you want to dress up the time duration graph with.

[image: time_duration_before]
        <sup>Before create_time_duration sub procedure</sup>

[image: time_duration_after]
        <sup>After create_time_duration sub procedure</sup>